# Correct overloads for SpriteBatch.Draw to flip sprite horizontally

Tags: c#, 2d, sprites, monogame, scale

I want to flip my sprite horizontally while drawing and I can't figure out how to use the correct parameters without either an error or a warning about the method being obsolete.

This is what I assume it would be:

```
sb.Draw(NumbersGame.Arrow, resolutionRightArrow, Color.White, 
SpriteEffects.FlipHorizontally);
```

Except it comes up for errors for the color (cannot convert from color to rectangle) and the `SpriteEffects` bit (cannot convert from sprite effects to rectangle).

What is the correct way to lay out these arguments?

P.S: When I provide all the default values (says it's obsolete):

```
sb.Draw(NumbersGame.Arrow, resolutionRightArrow, null, null, null, 0f, null, 
Color.White, SpriteEffects.FlipHorizontally);
```

Comment: You can use Ctrl + Shift + Space to view the possible overloads of the selected line. That way you'll know which parameter to use. There's also a possible button for it in the toolbar, saying "Display Parameter Info"

Comment: Check out the documentation for right call for the method Draw() it shows multiple overload options. https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/xna/bb196426(v=xnagamestudio.42)

Comment: What is the overload you have used that did work, without the horisontal flipping?

Answer (score 1):

The obsolete function signatures have been removed.

There are only two complete `Draw` functions in monogame(all of the others fill in the missing parameters and call one of these two), one uses a destination `Rectangle` the other a `Vector2` position.

The only difference between the two is in the way the scaling techniques are applied:

The `destinationRectangle` size is calculated against the source rectangle size. Resulting in two division operations per call.

The `position` variant takes a `Vector2` position and a `Vector2` scale parameter.

Either way don't forget to subtract the `origin` from the position to get the top-left point.

### The Destination Rectangle Overload

```
public void Draw(Texture2D texture,
    Rectangle destinationRectangle,
    Rectangle? sourceRectangle,
    Color color,
    float rotation,
    Vector2 origin,
    SpriteEffects effects,
    float layerDepth)
```

**texture** - The Texture2D object to be drawn.

**destinationRectangle** - The drawing bounds on screen. Scales to the width and height of the given rectangle.The position of the rectangle is the top left - the origin parameter.

**sourceRectangle** - An optional region on the texture which will be rendered. If null - draws full texture.

**color** - A value multiplied to each of the final pixels; RGBA clamped to 0-1. This can only darken colors, or increase transparency.

**rotation** - A rotation of this sprite in radians.

**origin** - Center of the rotation. 0,0 by default. A

**effects** - FlipHorizontal or FlipVertical. Can be combined with `|`.

**layerDepth** - A depth of the layer of this sprite. Order that the sprite is drawn. Can be any value. This value is used as the Z coordinate for the drawn quad.

### The Vector2 Position Overload

```
public void Draw (Texture2D texture,
                Vector2 position,
                Rectangle? sourceRectangle,
                Color color,
                float rotation,
                Vector2 origin,
                Vector2 scale,
                SpriteEffects effects,
                float layerDepth)
```

**texture** - The Texture2D object to be drawn.

**position** - The Top Left corner - the origin parameter.

**sourceRectangle** - An optional region on the texture which will be rendered. If null - draws full texture.

**color** - A value multiplied to each of the final pixels; RGBA clamped to 0-1. This can only darken colors, or increase transparency.

**rotation** - A rotation of this sprite in radians.

**origin** - Center of the rotation. 0,0 by default.

**scale** - The size scaling of the `sourceRectangle` size values.

**effects** - FlipHorizontal or FlipVertical. Can be combined with `|`.

**layerDepth** - A depth of the layer of this sprite. Order that the sprite is drawn. Can be any value. This value is used as the Z coordinate for the drawn quad.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this overload?

```
public void Draw(Texture2D texture, Rectangle destinationRectangle, Rectangle? sourceRectangle, Color color, float rotation, Vector2 origin, SpriteEffects effects, float layerDepth);
```

Comment: What value do I need to use for `layerDepth`? -100, -1, 0, 1, and 100 don't work.

Comment: It can range from 0 to 1f, try 0.5f for example

Comment: This answer could benefit from an explanation as to why this particular overload solves OPs problem.